# Could someone explain this step in the integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a}\int_{-a}^ae^{-x^2/a^2} dx$ when given $\int_{-1}^1e^{-u^2}du = 1.494$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The solution to question I've been given is:

> $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a}\int_{-a}^ae^{-x^2/a^2} dx$$
>
> $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a}\int_{-a}^ae^{-u^2} du$$
>
> $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a} \times 1.494a \approx 0.84$$
>   given that, using the substitution $u = \frac{x}{a}$:
>
> $$\int_{-a}^ae^{-x^2/a^2} dx=a\int_{-1}^1e^{-u^2} du = 1.494a$$

I thought it would be:

> $$\int_{-a}^ae^{-x^2/a^2} dx=a\int_{-a}^ae^{-u^2} du = a^2\int_{-1}^1e^{-u^2} du  =1.494a^2$$

I would appreciate it if someone could explain why this isn't the case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a}\int_{-a}^ae^{-x^2/a^2} dx$$

$u = x / a \Rightarrow a du = dx$

$x = a \Rightarrow u = 1$

$$
\begin{aligned}
P
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a}
\int_{-1}^1  e^{-u^2} \, a du
\\
&=
\frac{a}{\sqrt{\pi}a}
\int_{-1}^1  e^{-u^2} \,  du
\\
&=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\int_{-1}^1  e^{-u^2} \,  du
\\
&\approx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
1.494
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand that the substitution of $dx$ for $du$ gives us an extra $a$.  But why do the limits of the integral change to $1$ and $-1$?  Sorry if I'm missing a trick.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the limits require $a=1$ rather than $u=1$?

Comment: The original integral is over $x$ with limits $x =\pm a$ after changing variable to get the new integral we also need to convert the limits. Because $x/a=u$ we need to use the limits $u=\pm 1$ in the converted integral.

Answer (score 1):

note that $dx=adu$ thus integral turns to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} a} \int _{-1} ^ 1 e^{-u^2} .adu$ thus the result follows

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand this step, but why do we go from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} a} \int _{-a} ^ a e^{-u^2} .adu$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} a} \int _{-1} ^ 1 e^{-u^2} .adu$.  Apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: No when you substitute integral is in u not x so limits change from -a,a to -1,1

Comment: Would you mind explaining that particular process for me?  My attempt would be $a=\frac{x}/{u}$.  So the limits would become + and - $\frac{x}{u}$.  Then that would have to equal + and - $\frac{x}{u}=1$ and so $x=u$?  As you can probably tell I'm very confused about the limit change in particular.

Comment: when x=a we have $u=\frac{x}{a}=\frac{a}{a}=1$ similarly for other limit

Comment: Is $x=a$ because $\int_{x_{1}}^{x_2} = \int_{-a}^a$?  If so, I think we have found the source of my idiocy.

Comment: I've managed to answer some similar questions successfully at this point and indeed this basic definition is what I lost sight of.  I am going to mark Paul's answer as correct due to the answer itself having more detail, but thanks for your help.